# gradle project sync failed in Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to android development and just installed Android studio version 3.0.1. I just started my first project and it's showing the below error:-

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
```

It did suggest me to download and install SDK and NDK in the previous attempts which I did,successfully as it didn't suggest again. Now along with the above error, it also specifies the below statement:-

```
Error:Unable to get the CMake version located at: C:\Android\SDK\cmake\bin
```

I tried searching for `SDK manager` to install `Cmake` but I couldn't find it in `Tools` menu where it's supposed to be present.
[image: Screen shot]
 Please help me resolve this error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps**

**1**.You should open SDK Manager

**2**.Then click on SDk tools

**3.**. Download Cmake.

**If you can't find Sdk,then try download SDk from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and expand in the main directory and then set the path for it**